# variable not found in javascript in safari browser (macbook)

Tags: javascript, arrays, safari, prototype, indexof

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj3pb8xd/) in which images **fade-out/fade-in** after a specific interval of time. I have achieved this through JS. Here is the code which I have used:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block'));
    document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi')[0].classList.add('featured-block__item-multi-active');
    const pics = document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi');
    const lastPic = pics.length - 1;
    const transitionDuration = 500; // matches CSS
    let transitionDelay = 4*
    1000;
    const totalDelay = transitionDuration + transitionDelay;
    const intervalDelay = (transitionDuration * 2) + transitionDelay; // time to fade out + time to fade in + time to stay featured-block__item-active

    function toggleClass() {
        const activePic = document.querySelector('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi-active');
        const activeIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(pics, activePic);  // Line A
        const nextIndex = activeIndex === lastPic ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
        const nextPic = pics[nextIndex];

        setTimeout(() => activePic.classList.remove('featured-block__item-multi-active'), transitionDelay);
        setTimeout(() => nextPic.classList.add('featured-block__item-multi-active'), totalDelay);
    }

    setInterval(toggleClass, intervalDelay);
}
```

The above code seems to work fine on my *windows pc* but its not working on **safari (macbook)**. At **Line A**, I am getting error **Can't find variable of pics**.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make at **Line A** so that it works on safari (macbook).

Comment: Your fiddle works fine on my Safari Mac (12.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your documents loaded

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  
  if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block'));
    document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi')[0].classList.add('featured-block__item-multi-active');
    const pics = document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi');
    const lastPic = pics.length - 1;
    const transitionDuration = 500; // matches CSS
    let transitionDelay = 4*
    1000;
    const totalDelay = transitionDuration + transitionDelay;
    const intervalDelay = (transitionDuration * 2) + transitionDelay; // time to fade out + time to fade in + time to stay featured-block__item-active

    function toggleClass() {
        const activePic = document.querySelector('.featured-block .featured-block__item-multi-active');
        const activeIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(pics, activePic);  // Line A
        const nextIndex = activeIndex === lastPic ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
        const nextPic = pics[nextIndex];

        setTimeout(() => activePic.classList.remove('featured-block__item-multi-active'), transitionDelay);
        setTimeout(() => nextPic.classList.add('featured-block__item-multi-active'), totalDelay);
    }

    setInterval(toggleClass, intervalDelay);
  }

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms ease; /* immediately start fading out when active class is lost */
}
.pic.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="pic active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%204" alt="">
</div>
```